# How to return all subsets of size k of a set using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, set

I am completing a lab assignment in which I need to return all of the subsets of a certain size k using recursion. The function accepts the set S and this value of k. I am doing this in Java; I have already seen answers to this question, but they're in C and I am struggling to make the connections between the two languages.

I have already written a function to find the powerset of a given set S using recursion and understand how that code works (shown below). I am struggling the most with figuring out base and recursive cases for this problem, so I haven't really had any success in writing code that works. For the problem, we are not allowed to create a powerset from the function we already wrote and then choose the subsets of correct size; we must do it more efficiently.

```
public static Set<Set<String>> allSubsets(Set<String> s) {
    Set<Set<String>> pSet = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> temp = new HashSet<>();
    temp.addAll(s);

    // base case
    // if temp is empty set, add the empty set to the powerset
    if (temp.isEmpty()) {
        pSet.add(temp);
    }

    // recursive case
    else {
        Iterator<String> itr = temp.iterator();
        String current = itr.next();
        temp.remove(current);
        Set<Set<String>> pSetTemp = allSubsets(temp);
        for (Set<String> x : pSetTemp) {
            pSet.add(x);
            Set<String> copySubset = new HashSet<>();
            copySubset.addAll(x);
            copySubset.add(current);
            pSet.add(copySubset);
        }
    }

    return pSet;

}
```

Like I said, this code works, I just cannot solve the second part of the lab asking for a function that finds subsets of specific size k.

Comment: If you can find all subsets, what prevents you from adding only the subsets of size k to the result?

Comment: My professor has specified that we should not do that as it is not efficient. If we had a set S of size 100, for example, we would have 2^100 subsets within the powerset. If we only want subsets of size 2, we would have to loop through all of the subsets to get those.

Comment: You say “The function accepts ... this value of k”, but the code you’ve posted doesn’t have k.   So you need to add parameter k - which we can describe as “the size of the sets to return” - and remember that when recursing we want to pass down (k-1) , and the recursion stops at k==0 (nothing to return)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in JavaScript that should give you some hints.

```js
function f(S, k){
  if (S.size == k)
    return [S]
  if (k == 0)
    return [new Set]

  let result = []

  for (let e of S){
    S.delete(e)
    let smaller = f(new Set(S), k - 1)
    for (let s of smaller){
      s.add(e)
      result.push(s)
    }
  }

  return result
}

var S = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

console.log(JSON.stringify(
  f(S, 3).map(s => Array.from(s))))
```